# Removing people from pictures seemlessly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal

I'm currently trying to remove a person from a photo that tried to be cool and photobomb, but i'm at a loss as to how it can be done with no loss of photo quality.

My attempts have been to use the lasso tool to try and cut out as much of that person as possible, but to recreate the background behind is where I get stuck. Can anyone offer some advice on how this is done for folks that do this on a daily basis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method to do this or the decision to not do anything at all, depends a lot on the photo and what is supposed to be behind/around the person that should be erased from it.

Comment: For example: You take photo a painting in a gallery and later on realize that you have your fingers covering a whole lot of it. As good as it is, for this type of issue, content aware fill surely wont help. Are you going to paint it again or perhaps just leave it be and move on?

Comment: WEll the photo in question is of some twit photobombing the shot. I might be able to scoop together enough of the background to replace it. If not, a blank background and then doing a green-screen type thing will probably have to happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you are looking for recreating background is **content aware fill**, which is already part of your photoshop (if you have a recent one). **Google** those exact words for tutorials and videos how to use it. Also, **Adobe Help** describes the use of this tool.